# How to Make A button Clickable after some seconds when user click checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have make a button but I want the button to be `disabled` by default and the way to enable the button is the user must click on the checkbox after check box the button will show seconds counting after 3 seconds button will be able to gets click.

Here is my HTML for my button

```
<button type="submit" class="MY_CLASS" id="MY_ID">Claim Your Coin</button>
```

I have make a simple interface so you will easily know what I want to do. Please check images to understand very easily

Method one EXAMPLE one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY9F8.jpg

Method two EXAMPLE two (I am mentioning the method two for future use):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sguq2.jpg

So i got the code for method one (dont get for method two still)

But i was meant to show countdown of seconds going down on my button when the user click on the check box here is the code Can someone improve it

```
function toggle(){
setTimeout(function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("claim");
var chk = document.getElementById("chk");
debugger;
btn.disabled = !chk.checked;
},3000);
}
</script>
<label><input id = "chk" onchange= "toggle();" type="checkbox" 
name="checkbox" value="value">Click on the check box to enable 
button</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-
dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button disabled type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="claim">Claim Your 
Coin</button>
```

Comment: simply use a javascript onclick event handler

Comment: This is both too broad and unclear what you are asking. I wonder if you could edit the question to explain what you are stuck on specifically. Do you have any JS/jQuery code yet?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please move the images to the official image host for Stack Overflow, on `imgur.com`, by using the image uploader in the editor. Then, please add your current attempt. We discourage asking a question before a solid and genuine effort has been made, so that questions do not become requests for free work.

Comment: @halfer okay , i am moving images to imgur btw i have tried my best to simple my question i even got an answer on my first method , thanks , one more question when i add answer it comes in middle not on the bottom aint there any way for my answer to go down ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function toggle(){
setTimeout(function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("MY_ID");
var chk = document.getElementById("chk");

btn.disabled = !chk.checked;
},3000);
}
```

```html
<label><input id = "chk" onchange= "toggle();" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Click on the check box to enable button</label>
<button disabled type="submit" class="MY_CLASS" id="MY_ID">Claim Your 
Coin</button>
```

One more snippet to allow showing the count down of seconds

```js
function toggle(){

var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
var time= new Date().getTime();
var interval= setInterval(function(){
  var newTime= new Date().getTime();
  var diff = newTime - time;
  feedback.innerHTML = "Time remained to change enablement:"+ (3000 - diff);
}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){
var btn = document.getElementById("MY_ID");
var chk = document.getElementById("chk");

btn.disabled = !chk.checked;
clearInterval(interval);
feedback.innerHTML = "";
},3000);
}
```

```html
<label><input id = "chk" onchange= "toggle();" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Click on the check box to enable button</label>
<button disabled type="submit" class="MY_CLASS" id="MY_ID">Claim Your 
Coin</button>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Comment: When i am changing from MY_ID to my actual button id this is not working

Comment: Great. Glad I can help.

Comment: Welcome , waiting for someone to do improvement with your code so people can see the timer counting down

Comment: You mean to show how much time is left before the button becomes enabled or disabled? So users will know that the button enablement will change within 3, 2, and 1 seconds; something like that?

Comment: If so, I added one more snippet to have this feedback. It's in milliseconds. You may divide it by 1000 to be seconds instead.

Comment: yes you are right i mean to show how much time is left before the button becomes enabled So users will know that the button enablement will change within 3, 2, and 1 seconds

Comment: Did you check the new snippet? I added this functionality but in milliseconds.

Comment: okay i chek the new snippet i thought the second will go down in seconds under the button other wise it will break down my website responsive template , BTW thank you

Comment: snippet not working when i am removing My_ID to claim :/ btw i just know that bots can automate this so i would like to say dont put your time here now i am looking for the script the bots are using for automating those things

Comment: I see. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var cb = document.getElementById ("cb");
var button = document.getElementById ("MY_ID");

cb.onclick = function (e) {
  setTimeout (function () {
    button.disabled = "";
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<input id="cb" type="checkbox" />
<button type="submit" class="MY_CLASS" id="MY_ID" disabled>Claim Your Coin</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JavaScript setTimeout method.
Here is the implementation in jQuery.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/jogegikebo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.MY_CLASS').attr('disabled',false);  
    },3000)
})
```

Your HTML will need to have the disabled flag to start

```
<button type="submit" class="MY_CLASS" id="MY_ID" disabled="true">Claim Your Coin</button>
```

Comment: @SumairAli Click on the JsBin link. Works for me. http://jsbin.com/jogegikebo/1/edit?html,js,console,output